# Detecting OS (XP vs 7)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, operating-system

Yes, I've heard a million times that there is no reason to want to detect OS, but I'm getting different behaviors on both Firefox and Chrome between Windows XP and the exact same browser version on Windows 7.  I've scoured the internet and turned up nothing that can do anything more than detect whether or not it is Windows.

I also can't find any information on whether there may be a feature difference between the XP/7 versions of the browser.  Any help would be -greatly- appreciated, as I'm really at wit's end with this one.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having? What looks or behaves differently? Detecting OS is not the way to go.

Comment: @elclanrs - +1, treat the problem, not the symptom.

Comment: The problem lies in CSS in both cases, but it's different depending on the page/browser.  I know I need to figure out what specifically the problem is...or should, rather, but this project has droned on so long I just want to throw an exception and be done with it.  I was hoping someone would have a simple fix for me. :/

Comment: Look at the useragent.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey I know...and that's always my attitude.  Except right now.

Comment: haha i mean ... u couldn't solve it, so u go to the community for help ... on how not to solve it, but work around it? seems weird

Comment: If the problem is CSS then you definitely don't need to detect OS... You should post the CSS code and describe the problem so people can help. What versions of FF and Chrome, etc...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Use case example: use of modern Javascript features not compatible with old browser. Detect old IE to give them a message to upgrade/switch browser. But you shouldn't ask Windows XP to upgrade because they can't install anything higher than IE8, so for them the message is "change your browser". For the other you can ask to upgrade their IE.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `navigator.userAgent`. In XP it contains `5.1`, in Vista `6.0` and in Windows 7 `6.1` as you can see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834(v=vs.85).aspx.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isWinXP = ua.indexOf('windows nt 5.1') > 0;
```